# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when trying to import vue.js inside js file in Django app

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, exception, syntax-error

I'm starting out using vue.js in a real django project, but I'm already encountering an issue.

I've installed npm in the venv environment, and installed the vue package.

I now want to create a Vue object inside a js file, so I use :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

But in the console I get this error

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

I've searched for this issue but couldn't find a good answer for my specific case.

How to proceed to use vue js via the npm package then ?

Comment: If that line is being used clientside from a `<script>` tag it needs to set to be of `type="module"` as those are the ones that are allowed to use the `import`/`export` statements, eg `<script type="module">`

Comment: In my Django app this script is called in the admin section through python code, so I did not personally include the js file via html

Comment: ok no one knows about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the better, but much harder approach is getting webpack and babel involved.  However, for my small project, that seemed overkill.  I made the node_modules directory visible to staticfiles finder:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "node_modules"),
)
```

Now I had to access them thru the STATIC_URL (for me it is "/static/").

```
import Vue from 'static/dist/vue/vue.js'
```